# for loop jump out after first error in python

Tags: python-3.x, loops, for-loop

There is an unknown directory in a website which  I would like to save all of its files. we have a for loop  here and I want to check 500 links and download whatever file exists between these 500 links..However, the moment the code encounter the first 404 it go out of loop. How can i solve this problem?
tip: I only know there is a pattern in file names. they are 10-15 characters number like: "14565434567.jpg" or "12343432128900.png" thats why I want to use for loop.

```
import urllib.request

   for i in range (1,500):
     print(i)
     bb=str(i)
     print(i)
     url="http://www.example.com/2020/images/{bb}.jpg".format(bb=bb)
     print(i)
     urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, "{bb}.jpg".format(bb=bb))
     print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `try-except` block:

```
import urllib.request

   for i in range (1,500):
     print(i)
     bb=str(i)
     print(i)
     try:
         url="http://www.example.com/2020/images/{bb}.jpg".format(bb=bb)
         print(i)
         urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, "{bb}.jpg".format(bb=bb))
         print(i)
     except:
         pass
```

Comment: Unless OP want to continue on the 404 error only, your answer is legit to what OP asked.  Upvoted